# Windows Phone 8.1 Push Notifications BackgroundTask won't start

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on push notification in my Windows Phone App and I am having this issues.

From time to time the BackgroundTask which is responsible for push notification handling isn't wake up I know it- cause I've spread logs after each code line in my Task.

I know for sure that my token is valid and I am getting the notifications from the server.

This happens only when debugger is not attached.
I don't see any exception either in my log.

I can see in my logs, that one line before I am showing the Toast is cut at the end in a middle of writing (guess the task was terminated suddenly?)

Any ideas what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main problem was that I tried to use too many of CPU time , while writing logs and using my heavy application services (MvvmCross) such as Sqlite.

After removing logs, and heavy consuming time operations - everything worked :)